# java convert GB, Mb, KB, and byte to double with precision

Tags: java, numbers

Im downloading files in various sizes and like to
show user friendly output regarding the file size.

I have tried this:

```
double line= (totalBytes/(1024*1024));
DecimalFormat dec = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
String result = dec.format(line);
result = result.concat("MB");
```

That only works when the size is around one MB. If size is 1200000 bytes i get "1.2MB".
But how to make it dynamic if let say file size is 46 byte.

**UPDATE**
Howto show a size of 46 Bytes like this 0.000046MB or show 500KB like this 0.5MB.
This has to be done on-the-fly. I want the user friendly output to always show X.XMB
regardless of how many Bytes.

Comment: By the way, `(totalBytes/(1024*1024))` is doing an integer-based division. Try `totalBytes/(double)(1024*1024))` to get a floating point result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest solution is checking whether the number is larger/smaller than a factor and applying division accordingly.

So

```
if (totalBytes < 1024){

 //bytes
}else if (totalBytes < 1024*1024){
 //kilobytes

} //etc
```

Comment: yes that is what i want. but howto show a size of 46 Bytes like this 0.000046MB or show 500KB like this 0.5MB. Im updating my question it was wage

Comment: (double) totalBytes/(double)(1024*1024)

But then don't format the decimal as 0.00. Unless you're going to Ceil it. But I hardly think that 0.000046MB is 'user friendly output'

Answer (score 1):

Certainly, you will need

```
double line= ((double)totalBytes/(1024*1024));
```

Comment: thank you. btw, im updating the question since it was difficult to pinpoint what i need.